# Android Data Binding Listener View

Tags: java, android, xml, listener

At the moment I am learning Android Data binding. I tried some lambda code, but it does not work.

I am trying to call the `onClick` method from my XML code. Where is my mistake? Is something missing?

I looked at the Android documentation but they have a second parameter in their code like:

```
android:onClick="@{(v) -> fabBehavior.onFabClick(v, task)}"
```

I dont know what `task` is.

**XML:**

```
    <data>

        <variable
            name="buttonAction"
            type="com.sarahp.buttonaction.ButtonAction"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.sarahp.buttonaction.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> buttonAction.onFabClick(v)}"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_b"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> buttonAction.onFabClick(v)}"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**Java:**

```
public class ButtonAction{

    public void onFabClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.fab_a:
                Toast.makeText(context, "A Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.fab_b:
                Toast.makeText(context, "B Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

**MAIN:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

Comment: its a varable like yours `buttonAction`

Comment: it isnt it does not work

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: the code does not work

Comment: what does `"the code does not work"` mean?

Comment: this line does not work. the buttons doing nothing:             android:onClick="@{(v) -> buttonAction.onFabClick(v)}"

Comment: read https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#binding_data, note `binding.setUser(user);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an instance of the ButtonAction class to the layout file.

It can be done by

```
      activityMainBinding.setButtonAction(new ButtonAction());
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the class to your xml layout 
follow 'Bhupendra Joshi'